# Namedpipe writeFIle questions Win32

Tags: winapi, named-pipes

I am writing a win32 app which is using the namedpipe for inter-process communication. When one process is trying to writeFile, it will write the structure (tell other process how many bytes and other info), then it will write the actual data by calling WriteFile again.

The other process, when it is reading, it read the first msg, and then read the second msg based on the information got from the first msg.

My questions are:

1. If the server process is writing the data, but the client process hasn't read it yet, is it possible to lost the first msg when the client is reading? Example, when the server is calling WriteFile at the second time to write actual data, will the previous msg was overwritten?
2. Is there any best solution to use waitforsingleobject to sync?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pipe is a little like a real pipe -- when you write more to the pipe, it doesn't overwrite what was already in the pipe. It just adds more data to the pipe that will be delivered after the data that you previously wrote to the pipe.

I rarely find `WaitForSingleObject` useful for a pipe. If you want to block the current thread until it receives data from the pipe, you can just do a synchronous read, and it'll block until there's data. If you want to block until there's input from any of a number of sources, you usually want `WaitForMultipleObjects` or `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`, so your thread will run when any of the sources has input to process.

The only times I can recall using `WaitForSingleObject` on a pipe were with a zero timeout, so the receiver would continue other processing if there was no pipe input, and every once in a while check if the pipe has some data to process. While it initially seems like `PeekNamedPipe` would work for this, it's really most useful for other purposes -- though it might work for you, to read the header data and figure out what other code to invoke to read and process the entire message.

Having said all that, I feel obliged to point out that I haven't written any new code using named pipes in quite a while. I can think of very few situations in which I'd even consider them today -- I'd almost always use sockets instead.